# How do i iterate over an object which used getter in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here's the object defination:

```
var Vars = new function(){
    var that = this;
    this.assign = function(name) {
        var realValue = undefined;
        Object.defineProperty(that, name, {
            configurable: true,
            get: function() {
                //console.log("Get");    do something...
                return realValue; 
            },
            set: function(v) {
                //console.log("Set");    do something...
                realValue = v;
            }
        });
    }
    this.destroy = function(name) {
        return delete that[name];
    }
};
```

But i found i cannot iterate over this object by the way i want.

```
>> Vars.assign("key")
<- undefined
>> Vars.key = 1
<- 1
>> Vars.key
<- 1
>> for(var i in Vars){console.log(i);}
assign 
destroy 
<- undefined
```

How could i reach "key" when i iterate over the object?

Comment: you need `enumerable: true` as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to state explicitly at the property descriptor that your property is enumerable. The default value is false. This is the reason why you don't get it when you use the `for..in`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can
>   be executed.

Regarding the enumerable property, as it is stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

> **enumerable**
>
> true if and only if this property shows up during
>   enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object. Defaults to
>   false.

```js
var Vars = new function(){
    var that = this;
    this.assign = function(name) {
        var realValue = undefined;
        Object.defineProperty(that, name, {
            configurable: true,
            // This is the missing line
            enumerable: true,
            get: function() {
                //console.log("Get");    do something...
                return realValue; 
            },
            set: function(v) {
                //console.log("Set");    do something...
                realValue = v;
            }
        });
    }
    this.destroy = function(name) {
        return delete that.Local[name];
    }
};
Vars.assign("key");
for(var i in Vars){console.log(i);}
```